# How to get SUM of a column using join with distinct Records

Tags: mysql

check the image and reply me as soon as possible
Re: how to get distinct records sql server 
Posted on 19 Aug 2015
Table First

```
QuestionID(primaryKey)   TargetValue
1                         100
2                         500
3                         200
```

Second Table

```
RecordID(primaryKey)     Achieved Value  QuestionID(foreignkey)
1                               14           1
2                               14           1
3                               16           2
```

As per Manas told
Please find below query if you want to get 100:

```
SELECT SUM(Achieved) AS ACHIEVED, [Target]
FROM tabl1
INNER JOIN tabl2 on tabl2.QuestionID=tabl1.QuestionID
group by tabl1.QuestionID, tabl1.Target
```

1-I want to calculate SUM of Target and SUm of achieved not just target and sum of achieved
I want while calculating SUM of Target
`SELECT SUM(QuestionTarget)` will takes 100 regardless of how many rows in the second table against question 01 ....

if inner join create problem i have tried left outer join as well it also not giving the desired result

Comment: You _at least_ need to show expected output with a poorly worded question like this.

Comment: Agree, quite difficult to understand what you want to do...

Comment: my output add the target value for each record of second table like i am getting sum of target for question 1 =200 which need to be 100 it is 200 because in second table i have two rows against question one

Comment: Select SUM(Achieved), MAX(TargetValue) works?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query even your question is not much clear, if you are not getting desired results then show what output you need. Even you can create a sqlfiddle to get quick solution-

```
select questionid,sum(targetvalue) as target, sum(achivedvalue) as achieved 
from 
(
SELECT distinct tabl1.questionid,tabl1.targetvalue,tabl2.achivedvalue 
FROM table1 as tabl1
LEFT JOIN table2 as tabl2 ON tabl2.questionid=tabl1.questionid
) a 
group by questionid;
```

You can check output here in sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf590/1

Comment: You are calculating TargetValue i need some of target value the issue is that when i want to calculate sum of target for question id =1 it gives 200 which must be 100 it gives 200 because 2nd table have two rows against questionid=1

Comment: as per your shared data there will be single targetvalue for single questionid,  if you need some thing else then share what output you need.

Comment: yes there would be a single target value for one question id that also i want your query gives 200 as SUM OF TARGET which  need 100 ,i am  getting the 200 because, the second table has the two records with the questionId = 1. Which is a forgein key and giving the target value for two records as(100+100)

Comment: means you need targetvalue as 200 for questionid 1. is it right.

Comment: plz try modified query.

Comment: I need sum of target =100 For questionid=1 not 200

Comment: earlier query which i reverted again in my answer should provide you 100, if you are not getting same then plz create a sqlfiddle so that I can check the issue.

Comment: your query is getting 100 because you are not apply aggregate function on Target value i do not just want to get the first target value i need sum of all the target value the data shown in the table is for understanding purposes in real my table contains 100 + rows your query find the sum of achieved value and not sum of target value in sqlfiddle what i have to do i never used it

Comment: logically it is not possible as questionid in your first table is primary key then how you can store multiple totalvalue in first table..you can get help only if you provide correct details...further you can create sqlfiddle here.. i have already created a sqlfiddle for your problem you can modify here also.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3029a2/1

Comment: my Dear i mistakenly told you that it is primary key in Target table it;s not , in both table the Question_ID is foriegn key now can u provide a solution I have made a scrpit with data of my tables but sqlfiddle is not building my schema i can share my script with you ??but how

Comment: it says some thing went wrong  , sqlfiddle says that when building my query

Comment: you can check on your server...this error is due to network slowness you can try again here also.

Comment: I have given you the two tables can you assist the query if you need script then i will send you by email

Comment: i have updated query in my answer, please try it and let me know if you are not getting desired result. Did you try it....

Comment: your query Returns 15 rows instead of one row

Comment: query will return questionid wise row means how many questionid in first table query will return these no of rows...just click on sqlfiddle link updated in my answer and check if you want this or else...or you can change data here what you want.

Comment: you are right , but i have total 15 questions but in both table which we are using there is not primary foreign key relationship they both have foreign key and primary key is in a table Question(question_ID(P),QuestionText)

Comment: i need sum of all rows not individual rows based on question_ID